# Error in simple SQL update query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Table structure is like this

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tdnResetTickets](
    [ResetID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [userName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [tokenHash] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [expirationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [tokenUsed] [bit] NULL,
    [tokenType] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tdnResetTickets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ResetID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I want to update a column in that table. My query is like this

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tdnResetTicket] SET [tokenUsed] = 0  WHERE ResetID =1
```

And it throws an error

```
    Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.tdnResetTicket'.
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you selecting the right database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tdnResetTickets] SET [tokenUsed] = 0  WHERE ResetID =1
```

The Table is `tdnResetTickets` with s and Update Query is `tdnResetTicket`

Answer (score 2):

The Table is `tdnResetTickets` with s and Update Query is `tdnResetTicket`

Correct Code:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tdnResetTickets] SET [tokenUsed] = 0  WHERE ResetID =1
```

Answer (score -1):

Table name is incorrect in update statement.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tdnResetTickets] SET [tokenUsed] = 0 WHERE ResetID =1
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14578834)

Comment: UPDATE [dbo].[tdnResetTickets] SET [tokenUsed] = 0  WHERE ResetID =1